# Speeding up Mersenne prime generator

Tags: java, algorithm, primes

I am writing a program to calculate Mersenne primes.  This code works, but it is so slow:

```
import java.math.BigInteger;
import java.util.Scanner;
class calculate{
    private static Scanner scanner;
    public static  boolean MPtest(int x) {
         if (x < 2) throw new IllegalArgumentException("x must be greater then 2.");
         BigInteger lucas = new BigInteger("4");    
         BigInteger two = new BigInteger("2");    
         BigInteger one = new BigInteger("1");    
         BigInteger zero = new BigInteger("0");    
         BigInteger mprime = new BigInteger("1");    
         boolean test;
         mprime= mprime.shiftLeft(x).subtract(one);
         for(int i = 1; i <= x-2; i++) {
         lucas=lucas.multiply(lucas).subtract(two).mod(mprime);
         }
         test= (lucas.compareTo(zero) == 0);
         return (boolean) test;
    };
    public static final int floorSqrt(final int x) {  
        return (int) StrictMath.sqrt(x & 0xffffffffL);  
    }   
    public static final int floorSqrt(final long x) {  
        if ((x & 0xfff0000000000000L) == 0L) return (int) StrictMath.sqrt(x);  
        final long result = (long) StrictMath.sqrt(2.0d*(x >>> 1));  
        return result*result - x > 0L ? (int) result - 1 : (int) result;  
    }  
    public static final BigInteger floorSqrt(final BigInteger x) {  
        if (x == null) return null;  
        {    
          final int zeroCompare = x.compareTo(BigInteger.ZERO);    
          if (zeroCompare <  0) return null;    
          if (zeroCompare == 0) return BigInteger.ZERO;    
        }    

        int bit = Math.max(0, (x.bitLength() - 63) & 0xfffffffe); // last even numbered bit in first 64 bits  
        BigInteger result = BigInteger.valueOf(floorSqrt(x.shiftRight(bit).longValue()) & 0xffffffffL);  
        bit >>>= 1;  
        result = result.shiftLeft(bit);  
        while (bit != 0) {  
          bit--;  
          final BigInteger resultHigh = result.setBit(bit);  
          if (resultHigh.multiply(resultHigh).compareTo(x) <= 0) result = resultHigh;  
        }  

        return result;  
    };
    private static boolean isPrime(int n){
        if (n % 2 == 0)
            return (n==2);
        if (n % 3 == 0)
            return (n==3);
        int m = (int) Math.floor(Math.sqrt(n));
        for (int i = 5; i <= m; i += 6) {
            if (n % i == 0)
                return false;
            if (n % (i + 2) == 0)
                return false;
        };
        return true;
    };
    private static boolean isBigPrime(BigInteger n){
        BigInteger two = BigInteger.valueOf(2);
        BigInteger three = BigInteger.valueOf(3);

        BigInteger nc = n;
        if (nc.mod(two) == BigInteger.ZERO)
            return (n.equals(2));
        nc = n;
        if (nc.mod(three) == BigInteger.ZERO)
            return (n.equals(3));
        BigInteger m = floorSqrt(n); //Math.floor(Math.sqrt(n));
        BigInteger six = new BigInteger("6");
                                                 /*i <= m*/
        for (BigInteger i = new BigInteger("5"); m.compareTo(i) > -1; i.add(six)) {
            nc = n;
            if (nc.mod(i) == BigInteger.ZERO)
                return false;
            nc = n;
            BigInteger i2 = i;
            i2.add(two);
            if (nc.mod(i2) == BigInteger.ZERO)
                return false;
        };
        return true;
    };
    public static void main(String args[]){
        System.out.print("Number of primes:");
        scanner = new Scanner(System.in);
        int counter = scanner.nextInt();
        long start = System.currentTimeMillis();
        for(int y = 3; y < counter; y+=2){
            if(isPrime(y)){
                BigInteger mprime = new BigInteger("1");
                mprime = mprime.shiftLeft(y).subtract(new BigInteger("1"));
                if(isBigPrime(mprime))
                    System.out.println("2^" + y + " - 1 = " + mprime);
            };
        };
        System.out.println(System.currentTimeMillis() - start + "ms");
    };
};
```

What would be the best way to improve this?

Comment: You should look more into existing methods. There's `BigInteger.isProbablePrime` which is surely faster for big numbers.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### Bugs

> ```
> BigInteger i2 = i;
> i2.add(two);
> ```

This isn't right. If `BigInteger` were mutable, you would still change `i` as well. But since it isn't, you are changing neither. It should be:

```
BigInteger i2 = i.add(two);
```

The same problem here:

> for (BigInteger i = five; m.compareTo(i) > -1; i.add(six)) {

For me, your program never terminates, and this is the reason why. [See here for how to use `BigInteger` and loops.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3024186/java-how-for-loop-work-in-the-case-of-biginteger) It should be:

```
for (BigInteger i = five; m.compareTo(i) > -1; i = i.add(six)) {
```

### Other Improvements

> What would be the best way to improve this?

Right now, I would focus on readability, and after that is taken care of, look at the performance.

**Contradicting Exception Message**

> if (x < 2) throw new IllegalArgumentException("x must be greater then 2.");

The check and the message of this exception to not match. It should actually say that `x` must be greater than `1`.

**Static `BigInteger`**

There is no need to create a new object every time you call a method. It makes the code slower and harder to read. Just declare all the constant `BigInteger` you need once:

```
private static BigInteger two = new BigInteger("2");
private static BigInteger three = new BigInteger("3");
private static BigInteger five = new BigInteger("5");
private static BigInteger six = new BigInteger("6");
```

**`BigInteger` zero and one**

`BigInteger` actually has a [constant for zero](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/math/BigDecimal.html#ZERO), no need to create an object for it:

```
test = (lucas.compareTo(BigDecimal.ZERO) == 0);
```

It also has a constant for one, so you should also get rid of all the `new BigInteger("1")` (again, for readability and performance).

**General Style**

It will make your code a lot more readable if you follow general style guidelines:

- capitalize class names (`calculate` -> `Calculate`)
- function names should start with a lower case letter (`MPtest` -> `mpTest`, or better yet: `mersennePrimeTest` or `isMersennePrime`)
- before and after operations and assignments should be a space (for example `test=` -> `test =`, `x-2` -> `x - 2`, `lucas=lucas` -> `lucas = lucas`, etc)
- no semicolon after curly brackets (`};` -> `}`

**Variable Naming**

- what's a lucas? lucas lehmer residue? In that case I would actually name it `lucasLehmerResidue`. It's a bit longer, but also clearer
- if you rename your function to `isMersennePrime`, `mprime` would be fine, but it could also be `mersennePrime`
- argument names: is there a reason that sometimes the argument is named `n` and sometimes `x`? If you cannot think of more expressive names, I would at least use the same
- short variable names: `nc`, `i2`, and `m` don't really express what they do
- loop variables: if there is no good reason for it, I wouldn't use `y`, but `i`

**Unused functions**

Why do you have `MPtest` when you never use it?

**Unnecessary Variables**

I don't see why you need `nc`. I would just remove it.

**Unnecessary Brackets**

In your return statements, you don't really need brackets. Instead of `return (n==2);` just write `return n==2;`.

**Curly Brackets**

Always use curly brackets, even for one-line statements, it makes code easier to read and avoids bugs.

**Comments**

You need more comments. Your class should have one saying what algorithm you use, as should your functions.

In my opinion, code like this:

> ```
>    if ((x & 0xfff0000000000000L) == 0L) return (int) StrictMath.sqrt(x);
>    final long result = (long) StrictMath.sqrt(2.0d*(x >>> 1));
>    return result*result - x > 0L ? (int) result - 1 : (int) result;
> ```

would also deserve a comment or two.